# Calculadora de primos en java

Tags: java, calculo

Tengo que calcular el primo que ocupa la posición que yo quiera, pero me estoy haciendo un lío con la lógica del cálculo y he probado a reempezar varias veces pero no doy con la solución y no veo donde está el fallo, pero crashea cada vez que lo pruebo

```
public int getPrimo(int position) {
    int primo = 0;
    int counter = 0;

    while(counter<=position) {
        while(esPrimo(primo)==false) {
            primo++;
        }

        counter++;
    }

    return primo;
}

public boolean esPrimo(int primo) {
    int counter = 2;
    boolean esPrimo=true;

    while ((esPrimo==true) && (counter<primo)){
        if (primo % counter == 0)
            esPrimo = false;
        counter++;
    }
    return esPrimo;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

el problema que tienes es que en la condición del bucle while: "esPrimo(primo)==false" siempre vas a llamar con primo = 0, ya que la primera vez llamas con ese valor y no entra en el bucle, por lo que no actualizará el valor y la siguiente iteración volverá a llamar con 0. Yo cambiaría tu función getPrimo por:

```
public int getPrimo(int position) {
    int primo = 0;
    int counter = 0;

    while(counter<=position) {
        while(esPrimo(primo)==false) {
            primo++;
        }
        primo++;
        counter++;
    }

    return primo-1;
}
```

Devolvemos primo-1 porque hemos añadido primo++ cuando ya habíamos encontrado el valor que queríamos.

Comment: Muchísimas garcias, funciona perfecto!

Comment: Me alegro! De nada.